# Firebase : Loggin in after logout stuck on loading

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, dart, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase authentication and when I Login or Register it works properly and advance me to the Home page but when I Logout, it log me out successfully 
But when I Login again it stuck on Loading screen

My app flow is: main->Wrapper->Authenticate->Login/Register->Home

Here is Wrapper:

```
class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  int _currentTab = 1;

  final _page = [
    Search(),
    Home(),
    Account(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(user.uid);

    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return
//        Home();
       }
}
```

Here is Login :

```
RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.green[400],
                child: Text(
                  'دخول',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                    setState(() => loading = true);
                    dynamic result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                    if(result == null) {
                      setState(() {
                        loading = false;
                        error = 'Could not sign in with those credentials';
                      });
                    }
                  }
                }
            ),
```

and here is signIn method implementation for FirebasE:

```
Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets stuck on the loading because you have two `setState`, whenever you are pressing the button the first `setState` is getting called and assigns true to the variable `loading`. You should change it to the following:

```
onPressed: () async {
                  if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                    setState(()async{ 
                       loading = true;
                       dynamic result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                    if(result == null) { 
                        loading = false;
                        error = 'Could not sign in with those credentials';
                      });
                    }
                  }
                }
```

Comment: I modified it as your correction, but now nothing happen and it does not even go to loading screen

Comment: I removed the loading  and in console it notifies me that it is signed in , but the problem is with the navigation that it does not go to Home page

Comment: do you have a condition for the loading in the build method?

Comment: After I get uid the Authenticate navigates to Wrapper with the uid and then Wrapper goes to Home

Comment: I deleted all loading code until the user can signout and sign in again easily

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215074/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-alex-ali).